# APÍ django-storages dropbox erro url pattern

Tags: python, api, django, dropbox

Eu estou utilizando a seguinte API:

https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/dropbox.html

Eu tenho exatamente tudo configurado, desde a lib instalada até as configurações do settings.py.

A lib 'storages' no INSTALLED_APPS e as três variáveis de conexão com o dropbox:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'
DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = 'meu_token'
DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH = '/media/'
```

Eu quero que os campos FileField e ImageField façam upload de uma imagem ou arquivo e este seja salvo na pasta /media/ do projeto e do dropbox, mantendo a imagem em produção, tendo a App criada e configurada para ser app_folder.

Se eu retirar as três variáveis de configuração do dropbox e tentar modificar ou adicionar uma imagem pelo django admin é possível, porém, quando retorno as variáveis e tento novamente, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
  ValidationError at /admin/catalog/product/6/change/
'C:/media/products/cortina-city.jpg' did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])*|id:.*)|(rev:[0-9a-f]{9,})|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'
```

Dá erro também no dropbox.py da lib:

```
C:\Users\evert\Desktop\Synth\SynthDev\myenv\lib\site-packages\storages\backends\dropbox.py in exists
                return bool(self.client.files_get_metadata(self._full_path(name))) ...
        C:\Users\evert\Desktop\Synth\SynthDev\myenv\lib\site-packages\dropbox\base.py in files_get_metadata
                                       include_property_groups) ...
        C:\Users\evert\Desktop\Synth\SynthDev\myenv\lib\site-packages\dropbox\files.py in __init__
                self.path = path ...
        C:\Users\evert\Desktop\Synth\SynthDev\myenv\lib\site-packages\dropbox\files.py in path
            val = self._path_validator.validate(val) ...
        C:\Users\evert\Desktop\Synth\SynthDev\myenv\lib\site-packages\dropbox\stone_validators.py in validate
                                      % (val, self.pattern))
```

Eu entendo que não está identificando o padrão do get da url. Imagino que o C: não deve ir junto na string e está indo, ou seja, 'C:/media/products/..".

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Everton , como esta seu arquivo urls.py ?

Comment: Tenho a configuração:
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoalmente eu acho que lidar com os arquivos estáticos no ambiente de produção é uma das coisas mais complicadas. Como a própria [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/) diz:

> Claro, como todas as tarefas de implantação, os problemas estão nos detalhes. Cada configuração de produção será um pouco diferente, então você irá precisar adaptar o esquema básico para atender suas necessidades.

Como não vou conseguir reproduzir seu erro com facilidade, lhe dou algumas dicas de segurança:

- Verifique para onde suas variáveis de configuração como STATIC e MEDIA estão apontando. Abas devem estar apontando para o um caminho no root do seu projeto.
- Verifique no momento em que esta subindo os arquivos qual o local desejado.

  ```
  FileField(upload_to='media/', null=True, blank=True) #exemplo
  ```
- Verifique sua urls.py. Você mencionou que esta usando:

  ```
   if settings.DEBUG: 
       urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
  ```

  Essa configuração seta seu 'static' para ser uma combinação da sua STATIC_URL e STATIC_ROOT então certifique-se que os dois também estão devidamente configurados em seu settings.py

  Usar:

  ```
   url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
  ```

  Embora não seja recomendável, lhe ajudará também a mapear seus arquivos 
  estáticos para suas rotas.
- Por fim rode `python manage.py collectstatic` e verifique se seus arquivos estáticos estão sendo devidamente importados para o dropbox. Tenha em mente que quando rodar o collectstatics todos os seus arquivos estáticos terão de ir para o caminho definido no seu `STATIC_ROOT`. Tendo atingido essa meta você deve estar bem pois o [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) deve encarregar-se de servir esses arquivos.

Comment: Otávio, obrigado pelas excelentes dicas, porém, eu tenho tudo configurado e aparentemente está ok. 

No meu settings.py: MEDIA_URL = '/media/'; STATIC_URL = '/static/'; MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'); STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

Comment: O atributo imagem está assim: image = models.ImageField('Imagem', upload_to='products', blank=True, null=True). Dessa forma será criada uma pasta 'products' dentro de media. Como funciona normalmente local.